# Redirected to login page by spring acl plugin even after the user is already logged in?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have used spring acl plugin for adding permissions on objects so that a user owning one object cannot access object owned by another user.

In a number of controller update methods, i have to check if the write permission is available on the user executing the action so the first line is normally

```
myAclService.hasWritePermission(id, Event)
```

This method will throw access denied exception if the permission is not found.

Now my dilemma is that even after the user is logged in and the controller method is hit, often the user is redirected to login page. Is this is a weakness in the spring security plugin that is causing this behavior. I am wondering whether this redirection can be prevented if the user is already logged in? Is anyone else using the spring plugin having the same problem? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom handler for `AccessDeniedException`. There are more ways to do this. One way: create a global handler for all controllers by annotating a class with `@ControllerAdvice` and adding exception handling methods.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
 public void handleAccessDenied() {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null &&
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() &&
       //when Anonymous Authentication is enabled
       !(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() 
          instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) ) {
          // do nothing
       } else {
          throw new MyCustomException();
       }
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
  public String handleAccessDeniedForNotLoggedInUser() {
    return "redirect:/login";
  }
```

Also I believe it would be more readable to use ACL expressions in SpEL.
You can annotate controller methods with expressions like `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#event, 'WRITE')")` if you set up ACL by Spring guidelines and I believe Spring would then eat those exceptions silently and no redirecting would occur.